# Json_decode is not taking values from an array

Tags: php, json

I am absolute beginner in PHP, but some years ago I managed to create this simple code which calculates the daily price of copper in Bulgarian leva (BGN)

Unfortunately today I found out that the variable `$copper_lv_per_ton` is empty and does not return anything

```
$copper_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/LME/PR_CU.json?limit=1&api_key=nXWf2HdsDzw6b4LK-moU'), true);
$currency_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=248e0a098c90432aabd9f17c98f9a030'), true);
$copper_lv_per_ton = $copper_data['dataset']['data'][0][2]*$currency_data['rates']['BGN'];
```

Thank you for your support!

I am really trying to solve it for hours and cannot find what is going on

[image]

Comment: Tip: Code looks fine to me, it might have been a temporary glitch in one of the two API's you're using. Current result is 17058.660775.

Comment: Please check the photo I just added. It says 0 for me :( and everything seems fine in the code :(

Comment: I see. Well, the next step would be to check the URL's directly, in your browser. Can you see both results, like I do? Then check the values of `$copper_data` and `$currency_data` using [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump), do you see both arrays?

Comment: Another tip: Do not use an website to check your PHP code. Run your code on a proper webserver/PHP environment. These PHP services have disabled a lot of functionality, like, for instance, downloading an external file.

Comment: I checked the URLs and they are working. var_dump() returns "NULL" for both $copper_data['dataset']['data'][0][2] and $currency_data['rates']['BGN']

Comment: I recommended to check `$copper_data`, not `$copper_data['dataset']['data'][0][2]`. You first need to know you get something before you can extract data from it.

Comment: @KIKO Software - Thank you very much my friend!

Comment: Everything is fine now. I wrote the answer . Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared from my Joomla website, where I get the variables and used them in a formula without seeing any errors or debug happening.

Then I tried the code in the W3Schools compiler and it was not working again.
Then @KIKO Software suggested to not use online compilers for such a thing and put it on my own webserver.

I did so and found out the following error
[image: https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0]

Then I just changed `allow_url_fopen:` to `ON` in PHP Manager (CPANEL) and everything just worked.

Thank you for the support! Wish a lot of health to everybody

Comment: Ah, you must have updated/renewed your PHP environment. Yes, error messages can be quite useful. I could have suggested to check those.... :-)